# Using scrapy, how to make xpath more selective?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to obtain an [article](http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/04/03/net-us-internet-usage-idUSBRE83209D20120403).

```
>>> articletext = hxs.select("//span[@id='articleText']")
>>> for p in articletext.select('.//p'):
...     print p.extract()
...
<p class="byline">By Patricia Reaney</p>
<p>
        <span class="location">NEW YORK</span> |
        <span class="timestamp">Tue Apr 3, 2012 6:19am EDT</span>
</p>
<p><span class="articleLocation">NEW YORK</span> (Reuters) - Ba
track of finances, shopping and searching for jobs are the mai
et users around the globe, according to a new international 
survey.</p>
<p>Nearly 60 percent of people in 24 countries used the web to
account and other financial assets in the past 90 days, making
ar use of the Internet.</p>
<p>Shopping was not far behind at 48 percent, the Ipsos poll fo
 and 41 percent went online in search of a job.</p>
<p>"It is easy. You can do it any time of the day and most of t
on't have fees," said Keren Gottfried, research manager for Ips
Affairs, about banking online.</p>
```

I wish to remove the byline, timestamp and articlelocation, leaving only the article. Or even better, extract only the article. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
articletext = hxs.select("//span[@id='articleText']/p[position()>2]")
```

Which should return these 3 `<p>` tags:

```
<p><span class="articleLocation">NEW YORK</span> (Reuters) - Ba
track of finances, shopping and searching for jobs are the mai
et users around the globe, according to a new international 
survey.</p>

<p>Nearly 60 percent of people in 24 countries used the web to
account and other financial assets in the past 90 days, making
ar use of the Internet.</p>

<p>Shopping was not far behind at 48 percent, the Ipsos poll fo
 and 41 percent went online in search of a job.</p>
<p>"It is easy. You can do it any time of the day and most of t
on't have fees," said Keren Gottfried, research manager for Ips
Affairs, about banking online.</p>
```

But you'll probably have to remove the articleLocation manually after that.

Comment: When doing this, what returns is "<p>"It is easy. You can do it any time of the day and most of t
on't have fees," said Keren Gottfried, research manager for Ips
Affairs, about banking online.</p>"

Comment: Thats odd, is the code example true to real life then? Or are you testing aginst the output. That `p` is the 4rd in my example, but the 6th in yours. Which suggests something else may be happening.

Comment: Oh the code example was the output. I use the source code from the link given. Your method will work though, I realized. I solved my problem with focusparagraph = hxs.select("//span[@class='focusParagraph']/p")
        articletext = hxs.select("//span[@id='articleText']/p")
        article=''
        for p in focusparagraph:
            ftext=p.extract()
        for p in articletext:
            atext= p.extract()
            article+=atext
        
        print ftext+article

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add conditions to avoid those `<p>`s. Try it like this:

`//span[@id="articletext"]//p[not(@class)][not(span[@class])]`

Meaning "all the P elements that do not have a class nor have children SPAN elements with classes". You can use more than one condition to filter :)